# How to enable automatic download of missing Android SDK packages in Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

During Google I/O 2016's [What's new in Android development tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csaXml4xtN8) a great new feature was quickly mentioned: Android Gradle plugin can now automatically download missing dependencies from Android SDK.

It's also mentioned in Android Gradle plugin 2.2.0-alpha4 [release notes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

How do I enable it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `gradle.properties` file in your project's root folder add the following line:

```
android.builder.sdkDownload=true
```

Note: at the time of writing this option is experimental. It looks like so far it downloads missing build tools and platforms, but doesn't attempt to update repositories where the support libraries or Google Play Services libraries live according to a [bug report/feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212309).

Edit: since now support libraries and other libraries from Google live on maven.google.com and not in local repositories, the note above isn't as important.

Comment: If you want to auto-download preview SDK components, also add e.g. `android.sdk.channel=2` to `gradle.properties`.

Comment: I did that and it tries to download it, but it fail because the licenses needs to be accepted, but I don't know how to do it, I tried with -y `./gradlew installDebug -y` but didn't work. any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I did:

```
gradle --refresh-dependencies
```

on the terminal, and it solved the problem.

Comment: simple and works