# Gradle Android SDK as dependency

Tags: android, git, gradle

I'm currently searching for a way to have the Android Gradle automatically install the Android SDK as an dependency, so that the build can complete unattended in our GitLab pipeline.
I already come across the gradle plugin "sdk-manager-plugin", but it is marked deprecated with a note to use the automatic download from gradle. But it does not seam to work. If I run "./gradlew" from within a newly spawned docker container with just java and git it does not work. Is there any way to have gradle download the correct SDK Version (specified with compileSdkVersion)?
And also accept the license terms?

I already tried adding "android.builder.sdkDownload=true" to the "gradle.properties" file, but it didn't seam to work (suggested here [How to enable automatic download of missing Android SDK packages in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339045/how-to-enable-automatic-download-of-missing-android-sdk-packages-in-gradle)).

Comment: Looks unlikely r.e. the licenses portion: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

Comment: yes, I've read that, but it still would not solve the problem of installing the SDK components first. Also I'm hoping to hear about a better way to accept the licenses...

Comment: Any chance you could create your own docker image with the dependencies rolled in.  I think that would be the path I would take. Plus then your build isn't going to suffer the time penalty to install the dependencies every time it runs ( if it is indeed possible to get it running properly)

Comment: I've also considered doing this, but I received the feedback (from coworkers), that if possible I should use the normal of the shelf java docker image and everything else should be done in the pipe. Also this would allow them to not have the android sdk on there notebooks, but still beeing able to contribute and to contribute to more projects with different sdk versions without potentially messing things up.